# Input field value doesn't update

Tags: reactjs

My form populates with the correct input fields using `function CareerPosition(props)` and populates with data from `renderCareerPositions(props)`. The problem is I can type in the input fields however the value of the input field doesn't update. Not sure why.

Path: `SingleInput`

```
const SingleInput = (props) => (
  <FormGroup bsSize={props.bsSize} validationState={props.error ? 'error' : null}>
    <ControlLabel>{props.title}</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl
      className="form-input"
      name={props.name}
      type={props.inputType}
      value={props.content}
      defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
      onChange={props.controlFunc}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
    />
    {props.error ? <HelpBlock>{props.error}</HelpBlock> : '' }
  </FormGroup>
);
```

Path: `Reactjs`

```
function CareerPosition(props) {
  return (
    <li key={props.uniqueId}>
      <SingleInput
        inputType={'text'}
        title={'Company name'}
        name={'position.company'}
        controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}
        defaultValue={props.companyName}
        placeholder={'Company name'}
        bsSize={null}
      />
    </li>

  )
}

export default class CareerHistoryFormPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const profileCandidateCollection = nextProps.profileCandidate;
    const profileCandidateCollectionId = profileCandidateCollection._id;
    const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps: ', careerHistoryPositions);

    if (careerHistoryPositions) {
      const newData = careerHistoryPositions.map((position) =>
      ({
        'position.uniqueId': position.uniqueId || '',
        'position.company': position.company || '',
        'position.title': position.title || ''
      }));
      this.setState({
        data: newData
      })
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }


  renderCareerPositions(props) {
    if(0 < this.state.data.length) {
      console.log(this.state.data);
      const careerPositions = this.state.data.map((position) =>
      <CareerPosition
        key={position['position.uniqueId']}
        companyName={position['position.company']}
        positionTitle={position['position.positionTitle']}
        uniqueId={position['position.uniqueId']}
      />
    );
    return (
      <ul>
        {careerPositions}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

render() {
  return (
<form className='careerHistoryForm' onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        {this.renderCareerPositions()}
</form>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: If possible can you provide any fiddle code? or can you show SingleInput class?

Comment: I've never done that before. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use codepen side to give a running code, so it will help users to give solution. Check below 
https://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw

Comment: I can't get it to work on codepen. The app populates the form with data from a database. I don't know how to reproduce.

Comment: The problem appears to be arround `defaultValue` within `CareerPosition(props)`. The problem is that if I use `value` the `controlFunc={this.handleInputChange}` which is the `onChange` handler errors.  `Failed form propType: You provided a "value" prop to a form field without an "onChange" handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use "defaultValue". Otherwise, set either "onChange" or "readOnly". Check the render method of "FormControl".`

Comment: Just as the error suggests, I think you need to replace defaultValue, as it only renders the first time, so it does not know when the state changes.

Comment: If I use value, the form renders however I can't type in the input fields

Comment: Please include the code for your `SingleInput` component. We don't know what `props` you are expecting on the component and/or how you are handling it.

Comment: @ickyrr please see update.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between your `defaultValue` and `value` in your `FormControl` Component? I think it's redundant. That's why you're getting the error. You have to use either `value` or `defaultValue` only. I can see you're using both. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example on handle state change on `input`s. Like I mentioned in my comment, you are using both the `defaultValue` and `value` attributes and I think that's why you are having that error. Read more about [Uncontrolled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) vs [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) if you want to dig more into it.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { text: '' };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
        const fieldName = event.target.name;
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ [fieldName]: fieldValue });
  }

    render() {
    return(
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onInputChange} placeholder="Enter something" />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('mainContainer')
);
```

Try out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ickyrr/5ugkro1r/) for the code above. I hope this helps you, somehow.